# Yii2 namespace autoloader doesn't find copied files

Tags: php, ubuntu, namespaces, yii2

I am running the Yii2 framework locally, and I want to reuse an model I created in a earlier project.

So I copy the file `TestForm.php` to the `models` directory, change the namespaces from `namespace backend\models` to `namespace app\models` and try to create an object from it with:

```
$model = new \app\models\TestForm;
```

Which gives me

```
Unable to find 'app\models\TestForm' in file: /var/www/html/operators/basic/models/TestForm.php. Namespace missing?
```

Which is weird because the namespace is correct.

However, if I create the file `TestForm.php` myself and copy the contents of the older file over, everything works fine.

What's going on?
(I use ubuntu 15.04)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your /models/TestForm.php you don't have specified the correct namespace eg :

```
 namespace basic\models;
```

Comment: i added namespace app\models; at the top of the form model